# Disable intro key except in textareas and input submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the best solution to disable the enter key except when clicking on a textarea or with the focus on an input submit

And if it is possible that the solution works in all or most browsers

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).keydown(function(event) {     
        if( (event.keyCode == 13) && ($(event.target)[0] != $("textarea")[0]) && (event.target.type != 'submit') ) {            
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```

(Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox 66.0.3)

Comment: sure,thanks :).Please edit your question with some details